# Redshift SQL Case Statement and WHERE Clause not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm running the following SQL script to create a table with information on which marketing efforts are driving people to my site for form fills.

The case statement for marketing source stamp does not work. My results still have values for search-brand-whatever for the marketing_source column when those values should now just read "google-adwords".

I'm also getting results with a createddate of 9/15/2015 and after when my filter clearly states createddate >= '1/1/2016'.

Any ideas?

```
create table temp.roi_inqs as (
Select 
a.ID,
cast(a.createddate as date) as date,
CASE
WHEN a.marketing_source_stamp__c = 'search%' then 'google-adwords'
ELSE a.marketing_source_stamp__c
END AS marketing_source,
CASE 
when a.contactid is null then b.email
when a.contactid is not null then c.email
end as prospect_email
from rjm_current.sf_campaignmember a
left join rjm_current.sf_lead b on b.id = a.leadid
left join rjm_current.sf_contact c on c.id = a.contactid
where cast(a.createddate as date) >= '1/1/2016'
AND (
campaign_marketing_type__c in ('A','C'))
OR
(campaign_marketing_type__c = 'B'
AND a.status in ('Registered','Attended','No Show')));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire predicate is of the form

```
A AND B OR C
```

If you don't put any parentheses, this means you're querying

```
(A AND B) OR C
```

When you really meant to write

```
A AND (B OR C)
```

As a general rule: Always put parentheses if you're mixing `AND` and `OR`

Comment: no luck! same error still occurs.
Oddly enough when I reference the table I created and in that query I say "Where date >= '1/1/2016'" it gets rid of the 2015 records and filters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Lukas Eder Answered my question for the date issue.

For the case statement I had to change the marketing_source_stamp__c = 'search%' to marketing_source_stamp__c LIKE 'search%' and that issue is solved.

```
CASE
WHEN a.marketing_source_stamp__c LIKE 'search%' then 'google-adwords'
ELSE a.marketing_source_stamp__c
END AS marketing_source,
```

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that you had a second question, sorry for that. Thanks for putting the answer here